# Laravel voyager charts

Tags: laravel-6

Estoy teniendo dificultades, para generar graficos con datos de la BD.
Trabajo con laravel 7, [voyager](https://voyager.devdojo.com/) y el paquete [LaravelChart](https://charts.erik.cat/), para los gráficos.

Hice los widgets en donde se va a mostrar la información de compras - ventas y coloqué datos manualmente. Pero a la hora de pasar el array con los datos por ej. de total compras mensuales, no logro dar con la manera correcta de hacerlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Concretamente mi problema es con el paso del dataset

Este es mi código en el widget, con el que intento hacer el la lógica para pasar el dataset purchases y logro obtener el array con las cantidad y posiciones.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Widgets;

use App\Purchase;
use DB;
use Arrilot\Widgets\AbstractWidget;

class Purchases extends AbstractWidget
{
    /**
     * The configuration array.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $config = [];

    /**
     * Treat this method as a controller action.
     * Return view() or other content to display.
     */
    public function run()
    {
       $purchases = Purchase::select(
           DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) as month'),
           DB::raw('COUNT(1) as count')
       )->groupBy('month')->get()->toArray();
       //dd($purchases);
        $counts = array_fill(0,12,0);
        foreach ($purchases as $purchase){
            $index = ($purchase['month']-1);
            $counts[$index] = $purchase['count'];
        }
        //dd($counts);
        return view('widgets.purchases', array_merge($this->config, [
                'counts' => $counts
            ]));
    }

    public function shouldbeDisplayed()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Cualquier ayuda, es bienvenida.
Gracias

Comment: has logrado algo? si logras algo lo escribes porfa

Comment: Hola @Juanzu, No, no pude hacerlo en el widget, por lo que hice una vista nueva para las gráficas.
Saludos

Comment: @Franciso Morales pero si te grafica con las consultas de la BD? Saludos.